# Returning user to line of code where exception occurred - Java

Tags: java, exception

When an exception occurs I would like to return the user to the line of code where it occurred at, opposed to having them input everything again. Is there an easy/simple way to do this?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double initialAmount = 0.0;
    String type = "";
    double interestRate = 0.0;
    boolean finished = false;

    try{
        System.out.print("\nInitial Amount: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        initialAmount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Compound/Simple: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        type = input.nextLine();

        if (!type.equalsIgnoreCase("compound") && !type.equalsIgnoreCase("simple")){ 
            System.out.println(type);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        System.out.print("Interest Rate: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        interestRate = input.nextDouble();

        finished = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("\n----- Please check that you have entered a corrrect value! -----\n");
        createUserInvestment(); 
    }
    Investment invest = new Investment(interestRate, initialAmount, type);
    return invest;
```

Comment: The whole point of throwing an exception is to interrupt the normal flow of the program.  If you don't want that, why not just loop on the interest type query until you get a value you like?

Comment: If you could "return to the line it occurred at", you'd just loop back to the `throw new IllegalArgumentException();` line. Then you'd throw an exception, catch it, and loop back. Then you'd throw an exception, catch it, and loop back. Then you'd throw an exception, catch it, and loop back. Etc...

Comment: don't throw an exception, just loop the input with `while(something is true or not) { ask for input }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to throw any Exceptions in the code.  The only code that requires a try/catch is the nextDouble() assignment.  This can cause an error because the input is not always a double, but assigning Strings is much easier and doesn't need to be caught.  To return to the line, surround the lines you want to be repeated in a while loop.  Within the loop, check the input with if statements.  When you get the input you want, end the loop with the break keyword.  This will continue to assign the variable until it's assigned to what you want it to be.
Be wary of unnecessarily using Exceptions.  Exceptions are objects and therefore more expensive on memory.  So, only use Exceptions if you can't handle the error with the program's logic.  I'm not saying you shouldn't use Exceptions, just that you should only use them in a scenario when the error cannot be handled with if statements.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to verify the input, just loop until the user provides a valid value. Better is not let the exception to be thrown, as this is an error indication, and you cannot go back to the exactly same line, the program is a flow... get the input in a loop, check if valid, break the loop when valid.